# Number of moles of acidified potassium dichromate required to liberate 6 moles of iodine from an aqueous solution of iodate ions

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox, aqueous-solution, stoichiometry

I came across this question in a recent exam I had taken:

> How many moles of acidified $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ is required to liberate 6 moles of $\ce{I2}$ from an aqueous solution of $\ce{I-}$ ?

So this is how I approached it (by writing the corresponding equations):

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}  
\ce{ Cr2O7^2- + 14 H+ + \cancel{6e^-} &-> 2Cr^3+ + 7H2O} \\ 
\ce{6 I- &-> 3I2 + \cancel{6e^-}}\\
\hline
\ce{Cr2O7^2- + 6I- + 14H+&-> 2Cr^3+ + 3 I2 + 7H2O}
\end{align}
$$

Clearly, every mole of $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ liberates $3$ moles of $\ce{I2}$ from an aqueous solution containing $\ce{I-}$.

So, I concluded that $2$ moles of $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ are required to liberate 6 moles of $\ce{I2}$.
But the answer key given to me says that the correct answer for this question is $1$. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Yes you are right, it should be 2 mol dichromate leading to 6 mol iodine. Can you balance the equation first (hand written), iodide ion is missing on the left hand side?

Comment: Oh yes. I'll edit it @M.Farooq. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Your answer is right, but only for the reaction you have written. There could be other reduction half-reactions that you might select, though based on the statement of the question, you have selected the correct oxidation half-reaction.

Comment: Be prepared that any task description can contain an error. If you underestimate your knowledge, overtrusting autority, you may not notice it.

Comment: @Zhe could you please tell what other reactions are possible?

Comment: Try consulting a table of half reactions. Judging by the expected answer, you're looking to reduce the dichromate down to elemental chromium, which, in all honesty, seems like a worse choice than what you've selected.

Comment: For the record, should be iodate not iodide. Here are cited reactions in the Briggs-Rauscher reaction with H2O2 replacing K2Cr2O7  in the presence of iodate:

Eqn. 1-4  5 H2O2 + 2 IO3- + 2 H+ -> I2 + 5 O2 + 6 H2O and 
 
Eqn. 1-5  5 H2O2 + I2 -> 2 IO3- + 2 H+ + 4 H2O